# How can I pass a variable to the sqlplus command in a shell script

Tags: sqlplus

I am writing a shell script that will do error checking against a file with usernames in it.

The user name file contains the following info and is named list1:

```
user1/user1@db301
user2/user2@db316
user3/user3@db311
user4/user4@db312
ect...
```

The error checking file contains the following info and is named error_check.sql:

```
select TAG_DATA from SITE_DATA where TAG_NAME='BULK_EMAIL_USE_CCCS'
select * from TASK_RECUR where RECUR_ID='111'
select * from TASK_RECUR where RECUR_ID='112'
select * from TASK_RECUR where RECUR_ID='113'
exit
```

I need to pass both variables to a shell script like so:

```
while read line; do sqlplus -S $list1 < $line < error_check.sql >> $LOGFILE; done
```

I have tried many different ways to do this but I am just not seeing the big picture here...  Can someone please help me to correct my issue?

Thanks in advance

Also please forgive the lack of proper formatting in this ... It was my first time.

Thanks again

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you write an example that shows exactly what you want to happen? What's the command line that runs sqlplus? If you were doing this all by hand, what would you type?

Answer (score 0):

The sql file should be properly formatted eg. each select statement need to end with semicolon;

You call the file as

@yourfile.sql blue

and use the value inside script as

select id from colors where color_name='&1';